# How to add Tabs to ActionBar for Swipe Tabs?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-tabs

I wanna create two swipe tabs with `ActionBar`.

This is my code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.R;

/**
 * Created by Salar on 9/5/2015.
 */
public class AccountsActivityChart extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

        actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Add the Action Bar Tabs
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Accounts Activity"+"Chart Activity").setTabListener(this));

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

when i run the app this error occurs:

```
> 05-11 06:09:28.013    2371-2371/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
>     Process: com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank, PID: 2371
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank/com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.AccountsActivityChart}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object
> reference
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on
> a null object reference
>             at com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.AccountsActivityChart.onCreate(AccountsActivityChart.java:21)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 05-11
> 06:09:30.037      444-504/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '155e1fbc
> com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank/com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.MainActivity
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
> 05-11 06:09:30.037      444-504/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '2f2170b7
> com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank/com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.Login
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

[image]

I really don't know what should I do!
Would you guys please guide me?
thank you so much.

latest code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.R;

public class AccountsActivityChart extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Add the Action Bar Tabs
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Accounts Activity"+"Chart Activity").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this tutorail... this will help you
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: with this tutorial i get this errors:
Unable to start activity `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you are creating a `FragmentActivity` and expecting to see an `ActionBar` which won't happen.

Replace

```
AccountsActivityChart extends FragmentActivity
```

with

```
AccountsActivityChart extends ActionBarActivity
```

Secondly, you need to call

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```

because `ActionBarActivity` is part of the `appcompat-v7` library. This is why your app crashes when you call `actionBar.setNavigationMode()`, because `getActionBar()` returns `null` when used with a `FragmentActivity`.

After doing this, you should be able to use

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

successfully and see swipeable tabs under your `ActionBar`.

**EDIT:**

Replace

```
import android.app.ActionBar
```

with

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

Comment: thank you so much @Y.S. I have made changes.
whene i change the actionBar=getActionBar() to actionBar=getSupportActionBar(); this error will show:
incompatible types: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar cannot be converted to android.app.ActionBar

Comment: see edited answer and let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: No it's doesn't work, i get this error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank/com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.AccountsActivityChart}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: post your latest code in the question and send me an update when done :)

Comment: Thank you Y.S. for answering me
in this Tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) the author said **public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {**
why u say use this: **AccountsActivityChart extends ActionBarActivity** ?

Comment: @SalarRastari: All I can say is that the author is wrong. Probably he made a mistake. The code you have updated above is correct. Is it working now ?

Comment: as you said i have made the changes but it's not working :(  @Y.S.

Comment: check in your manifest what style you have used for this `Activity`. It should be one of the `AppCompat` styles.

Comment: I use this Tutorial [Material Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) to create Material App

`<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: check if you have set `android:windowNoTitle` as `true` in your styles. This too can hide the action bar

Comment: no it's not working, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I need more details ... you are doing something wrong in the styles or the manifest that is causing the action bar to not appear